# Is there a special common term for the name of a film?

Tags: terminology

In the beginning of a film (or in the end) there are credits, or information about creators of the film: actors, producers, production designers and so on. [The example](http://titres.designcabaret.com/credits.png). And among credits there is the name of the film in big letters. Is there a special term for the name of a film?

For example, this:
[image: 2001: A Space Odyssey]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The term for the name of a film is "the name of a film" or "the title of a film".

Comment: @DavidRicherby he's asking about title cards. It's clearer if we see the image, but the rules on editing won't let me edit to show the image inline until the pending edit is either accepted or rejected.

Comment: @JonHanna I hate that feature of editing. The fact that you have enough rep to edit unilaterally should also let you approve other people's edits unilaterally, but it doesn't. Anyway, my edit has now been approved.

Comment: @JonHanna I did follow the link to the image but it didn't enlighten me. Is the question asking for literally "the term for the name of a film"? (In which case, the answer is near-trivial: "the name or title of a film") Is it asking for a term for the act of stating of the film's name in the opening credits? For the way in which it's presented?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I could be misinterpreting of course, but I think they are talking about the actual title card, as per my answer.

Comment: @JonHanna +1 for a good answer to something that *might* be the actual question. :-)

Comment: @JonHanna - that  is interesting, but you changed to original question to fit your own answer!! OP didn't mention the word 'title'.

Comment: @Josh61 I changed the question solely to make the image visible, as can be easily seen at http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/219997/revisions

Comment: @JonHanna - yes sorry.. The change of the wording was done by David Richerdy!!!

Comment: @Josh61 change it back to *titre* if you think that is more correct.

Comment: @JonHanna - no, the sequence is clear enough!!

Comment: @JonHanna, thank you for correction. But you didn't understand me and now my question is strange. 

By the "titres" I mean credits, or information about creators of the film, actors, producers, production designers and so on. The example http://titres.designcabaret.com/credits.png. 

On my first picture "2001: A Space Odyssey" is "the title of the film". I have got the collection of such "titles". So, I'm searching for the most appropriate headline for the collection.

I've got variants: "the movie titles", "the film titles" or "the title cards". What is the most appropriate?

Comment: Looking at the rest of the site, it has a lot of title cards in the wider sense I mentioned in my answer. Again both "title cards" and "titles" are appropriate. *Credits* is also used but sometimes excludes the image of the actual movie's name. I'd recommend "title cards" to focus specifically on the images and "titles" otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Title card*.

E.g [this listicle](http://www.gamesradar.com/35-greatest-movie-title-cards/) and indeed [this google image search results](https://www.google.ie/search?q=movie+title+card&tbm=isch) (content warning: One of the images that returns is from a horror film and gory, not terribly realistic, but don't say you weren't warned).

*Title card* is also used to refer to the static text that appears in the middle of some films, especially in the silent era, though this is less common now because the technique is less common. Those sorts of title cards are also now called *intertitles* while the title card with the actual title are not.

Title cards in both senses are also sometimes just called *titles*, but that can of course also refer to just the name of the film.

Answer (score 1):

I think [title](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/title) is the word you are looking for: (TFD)

> - a descriptive heading, as of a chapter of a book.

[Movie titles](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/alphabetical.htm?letter=D&page=2&p=.htm):

Comment: Well, «title» is too common, I suppose. Maybe there is some special word?

For example, I collect «film titles». I'm searching for the most aproppriate word for the headline of my collection. The collection http://titres.designcabaret.com/

Comment: No, _title_ is the word. What you're referring to as the "titres" I would call the _credits_.

Comment: Would "Film titles" be the best and the most appropriate headline for the collection?

Comment: Lists of films indexed alphabetically by title. Film titles or movie titles: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_films